# How to move to the next image using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem moving to the next image.like we move to next images in FB.
I tried but couldn't achieve it.
rightimage is the class of the right arrow

```
$('.rightimage').on("click", function (event) {

    var sectionId = $(this).parents('ul').attr('id'); // i get the current image
    var outputId = sectionId.replace('ul', 'img'); // i get the current image id
    var NextId = outputId + 2; //increment and assign it to another var

    if ($('NextId').length) { // see if the image with id exists    

        // here i have to put the image if it exists else i have to check or the next image
    }
    if ($('NextId+1' > rightImgcounter)) {

        // disable the button
    }
});
```

‘rightImgcounter’  is the global javascript variable which provides the sequence number to our right images. the imaegs are dynamicaaly generated.
 ain't knowing how to move to the right next image on the screen. and disable the button if there are no images next right.

Comment: FYI, the `.live()` method has been deprecated and removed in jQuery > 1.7. You should replace it with the `.on()` method.

Comment: Also, it would be very helpful if we could see the HTML. Try using jsFiddle

Comment: okay..i'll change it :)

Comment: Is the variable `outputId` a string or integer??

Comment: outputId contains 'img-1' , id is to be incremented

Comment: @DevlshOne i used plugins for fullscreen .so i couldn't put it on jsfiddle :-/

Comment: Yes @anuRadha I am here...

Comment: could you help  me with this. Please

Comment: Just wanted to know. what are you trying to do in this code `if ($('NextId+1' > rightImgcounter)) {`

Comment: i'm new to jquery..tried like if there are no images on the right.then the rightarrow is to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
// Using the jQuery version 1.7+
$('.rightimage').on("click", function (event) {

    var sectionId = $(this).parents('ul').attr('id');
    var outputId = sectionId.replace('ul', 'img');

    //var NextId = outputId + 2;    
    var NextId = outputId.replace(/(\d+)+/g, function (_, number) {
        return parseInt(number) + 2;
    });

    // Check the NextId in the console (for debugging purpose) 
    console.log(NextId);

    // see if the image with id exists 
    if ($('#' + NextId).length) {
        // here i have to put the image if it exists 

    }

    var counter = parseInt(/(\d+)/.exec(NextId)[0], 10) + 1;
    if (counter > rightImgcounter) {

        // disable the button
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: parseInt(/(\d+)/.exec(NextId)[0], 10) + 1// what do this return

Comment: It return the integer value + 1 in the string ID like from `img-1` it will return `2`, agian for `img-2` it will return `3` and so on..

Comment: will try and will post if i get it :)